# php curl removes a session when I parsing the file

Tags: php, parsing, session, curl, destroy

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"key=" . $value. " ");
$result = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

When I use curl sessions get destroyed. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean, your sessions are being destroyed? Are you trying to make multiple requests, like logging in? Check out curl cookie jars

Comment: yes am trying to make multiple requests.  How to Check cookie jars?

Comment: the code you've shown doesn't have multiple requests or any work with sessions, please provide a [mcve] to reproduce the issue

Comment: By cookies jars he means that you can make a login request, save the cookies which are being returned from that request into a file and use the same cookies for following requests. Take a look at the docs: http://php.net/manual/function.curl-setopt.php (find CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR) The cookies will tell the other server that you are authenticated (logged in) and so forth. (Of course cookies can expire, so keep that in mind)

Comment: ok. thank you friends :)